# Confused about sum of G.P. formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of $n$ terms of the G.P. $a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, \ldots, ar^{n-1}$ is given by $a\dfrac{r^n-1}{r-1}$.

Now consider these two progressions:

1) $r^2, r^4, r^6, ..., r^{2n}$

2) $r, r^3, r^5, ..., r^{2n-1}$

Both of these have $n$ terms. Therefore, $S_{n1} = r^2 \dfrac{(r^2)^n-1}{r-1} = r^2 \dfrac{r^{2n}-1}{r-1}$. Also, $S_{n2} = r \dfrac{r^{2n}-1}{r-1}$. It seems that no matter what $r$ be, the sum of even powers will be $r$ times the sum of odd powers. However, this is not true as a simple example shows:

Consider $r = 0.5$. Now, $r^2 + r^4 + r^6 = 0.328125$, while $r + r^3 = 0.625$, and $ 0.328125 \neq 0.625 \times 0.5$

Where is the error?

Comment: You did not use the same numbers of powers. Left out the $r^5$.

Comment: You wrote "Both of these have n terms", but in your example you consider 3 term for the even powers but only two for the odd.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last term of the second series is $r^{2n-1}=r\cdot r^{2n-2}=r\cdot (r^2)^{n-1}$, and the ratio of consecutive terms is $r^2$, not $r$, so the sum formula should be

$$S_{2n}=r\cdot\frac{r^{2n}-1}{r^2-1}\;.$$

The ratio in the first series is also $r^2$, so the sum formula yields

$$S_{1n}=r^2\cdot\frac{r^{2n}-1}{r^2-1}\;.$$

This says that $S_{1n}=rS_{2n}$, which is clearly correct, since

$$r^2+r^4+\ldots+r^{2n}=r\left(r+r^3+\ldots+r^{2n-1}\right)\;.$$

Your example doesn’t match your formulas: for $n=3$ you should be comparing $r^2+r^4+r^6$ with $r+r^3+r^5$, not with $r+r^3$.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that too! A typing error on my part. :)

Comment: @dotslash: I wish that I had a dime for every typing error that I’ve made!